# Anyway in Electron to remove the windows taskbar preview from my app?

Tags: node.js, electron

Anyway in Electron to remove the windows taskbar preview (not icon) from my app? Image of what I want to remove from my app:

[image: Image of what I want to remove from my app]

Comment: are you open to using .NET for that? I don't think there's an Electron API to accomplish this. I am using a .NET solution in my app

Comment: @pushkin could you by any chance give me more detail as to how you went about implementing it?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @Community idk looks pretty darn specific to me, I even provided a straight up picture of what I would like to remove, in the case that you have never used a version of windows since xp, there is not much I can do about that if you are not familiar with the windows taskbar.

Answer (score 1):

Set this on your window:

```
windowObj.setSkipTaskbar(true);
```

[See `.setSkipTaskbar(` documentation](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/api/browser-window#winsetskiptaskbarskip)

Comment: I believe this removes more than the preview. It removes the entire taskbar icon, and I'm not sure if that's what OP wants.

Comment: I just want to get rid of the preview not the icon itself.